# Displaying an array output with brackets and commas in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, formatting, brackets

I am trying to print the array in my program with brackets and commas. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int[] arrayIntList = new int[10]; // Starting the array with the specified length

    int sum = 0; // Defining the sum as 0 for now

    // Using the for loop to generate the 10 random numbers from 100 to 200, inclusive.
    for(int nums1 = 0; nums1 < arrayIntList.length; nums1++) {
        arrayIntList[nums1] = (int)(100 + Math.random()*101);
    }           

    Arrays.sort(arrayIntList); // Sorting the array list
    
    System.out.print("[");
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayIntList.length; i++) { // Printing the array
        System.out.print(arrayIntList[i] + " "); 
        }
    System.out.print("]");
    
    int[] arrayC = CalcArray(arrayIntList); // Sending the array to the method
    
    System.out.println("");
    
    for(int doubles : arrayC) { 
        System.out.print(doubles + " "); // Printing the output from the second method and calculating the sum
        sum = sum + doubles;
    }
    
    System.out.printf("%nThe total is %,d", sum); // Printing the sum
}

private static int[] CalcArray(int[] nums) {

    for(int nums2 = 0; nums2 < nums.length; nums2++) { // Doubling the original array
        nums[nums2] *= 2; 
    }
    return nums; // Returning the doubles numbers

}
```

The format I am looking for is something like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].
If anyone one could give me some pointers then that would be great.

Comment: First downvote, hooray!

Comment: what are you getting now? You need to put more information on the issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays.toString can do it for you.

More generally, joiners are intended for that :

```
System.out.println(
    Arrays.stream(array)
        .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]")));
```

Bonus : compute the sum  with `Arrays.stream(array).sum();`

Answer (score 4):

You should simply use the method `Arrays.toString`, it will do it for you, more details in the Javadoc [Arrays.html#toString(int[])](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int%5B%5D)).

Comment: When I try to use this in the for loop output of the array, I keep getting multiple errors through the code as the string type is not compatible with the int type. Is there somewhere else I am supposed to use this?

Comment: You call Arrays.toString(arrayIntList) directly, you don't need any loop

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this, if you want to implement it yourself:

```
int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("[");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sb.append(array[i]);
    if (i < array.length - 1) {
      sb.append(", ");
    }
}
sb.append("]");
```

Comment: Thing is, this is for a class assignment so I am not allowed to use these methods, only the ones mentioned in the chapter :(

Comment: Instead of the StringBuilder you can use a String directly.

Answer (score 0):

Just see Data Structures Concept on java.!It Will more helpful to you.!
The java **API** provides special class to store and manipulate group of objects. One Such Class is **Arraylist**

Note that **Arraylist** class is in java.util.ArrayList

Create an ArrayList as you would any objects.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
//..
ArrayList ajay = new ArrayList();
```

Here

ArrayList -> Class

ajay -> object

You can optionally specify a capacity and type of objects the Arraylist will hold:

```
ArrayList ajay<String> = new ArrayList<String>(10);
```

The Arraylist class provides a number of useful methods for manipulating objects..

The **add()** method adds new objects to the ArrayList.And **remove()** method remove objects from the List..

Sample Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> ajay = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int num;
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<5;i++){
            num=sc.nextInt();
            ajay.add(num);
        }
        System.out.println(ajay);
    }
}
```

Input: 1 2 3 4 5
Output:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

If you have doubt,please take tutorials on ArrayList on java..
Thank you.!